# angularjs directive to angular6 component/directive

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have one angularjs directive as part of old application, I would like to convert that into angular6, As I dont know angularJS and currently working with angular6 version, could anybody please help me with pointer ? below is angularjs code.

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';

    var base = require('base');
    var utils = base.utils;

    configCompile.$inject = ['$compileProvider'];
    module.exports = configCompile;

    function configCompile($compileProvider) {

        $compileProvider.directive('projCompile', projCompile);

        function projCompile($compile) {
            return {
                scope: {
                    compile: "=",
                    scope: "=?",
                },
                link: link,
            }

            function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                var scope_child = scope.$new();

                scope.$watch('compile', function () {

                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

                scope.$watch('scope', function () {
                        scope.scope = scope.scope || {};
                        scope_child = scope.$new();
                        for (var idx in scope.scope) {
                            scope_child[idx] = scope.scope[idx];
                        }
                        scope_child.$this = scope.scope;

                        element.empty().append(scope.compile);
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope_child);
                    }
                );

            };
        };
    }

})
```

Comment: SO is not a place where someone does the whole work for you

Comment: I thoroughly agree with you, but any pointer would be helpful, as  I searched through internet and did not find anything as such on this particular issue.

Comment: And you won't find anything. This requires a good knowledge of both AngularJS and Angular to make it right. Start doing at least something.

Comment: I dont know excately but we had compile directive in angularjs similar way I need the thing in angular6, see if you can help

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to forget about the angularJS code, focus on what the directive does. (It is not obvious from the code).

Once you know what purpose the directive is serving, if it is still needed, then lookup how to achieve that in Angular 6. If you can't find the answer then come back to Stack Overflow with more specific questions on how to achieve X in Angular 6, with samples of your attempts in Angular 6 code.

Comment: this is similar to $compile directive we had in angularjs, just for your knowledge,in chat messaing app this creates different messages as such